# On Saving Page info with dynamic Dropdowns getting Exception -You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting this exception when trying to save the record .

I have drop-downs which are being bound with the external APIs. On saving the record i am just using the selectedValue and it shows the exception. Please help to resolve this issue.

**Visual Force Page ---------**

```
<apex:page controller="CRMController" tabStyle="Prospect__tab">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="PROSPECT" id="main">
 <apex:pageMessages />
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SaveUpdateCRMInfo}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>

<table width="70%" border="0">
           <tr>
           <td width="20%" align="right"><apex:outputLabel value="Prospect Owner"/></td>
           <td width="1%"></td>
           <td><div class="requiredInput">
                    <div class="requiredBlock"></div><apex:selectList value="{!selectedOwner}" size="1">
           <apex:selectOptions value="{!OwnerOptions}"/></apex:selectList></div></td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td align="right"><apex:outputLabel value="Existing Client"/></td>
           <td></td>
           <td align="left"><apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedIsExisting}">
           <apex:selectOptions value="{!IsExistingOptions}"/></apex:selectRadio></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td align="right"><apex:outputLabel value="First Name" /></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><div class="requiredInput">
                    <div class="requiredBlock"></div><apex:inputText value="{!FirstName}" rendered="true"/> </div></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td align="right"><apex:outputLabel value="Last Name"/></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><div class="requiredInput">
                    <div class="requiredBlock"></div><apex:inputText value="{!LastName}" /></div></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td align="right"><apex:outputLabel value="Date of Contact"/></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><apex:inputText value="{!LeadDate}" /></td> 
           </tr><tr>
           <td align="right"><apex:outputLabel value="Channel"/></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><apex:selectList value="{!selectedChannel}" size="1"  styleClass="width">
           <apex:selectOptions value="{!ChannelOptions}"/></apex:selectList></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td align="right"><apex:outputLabel value="Status"/></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><apex:selectList value="{!selectedStatus}" size="1" styleClass="width">
           <apex:selectOptions value="{!StatusOptions}" /></apex:selectList></td> 
           </tr><tr>
           <td align="right"><apex:outputLabel value="Industry Type"/></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><apex:selectList value="{!selectedIndustry}" size="1" styleClass="width">
           <apex:selectOptions value="{!IndustryOptions}" /></apex:selectList>

           </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td align="right"><apex:outputLabel value="Expected Close Date"/></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><apex:inputText value="{!ExpectedCloseDate}" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td align="right"><apex:outputLabel value="Money Value (USD)"/></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><apex:inputText value="{!Value}" /></td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td align="right"><apex:outputLabel value="% of Close"/></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><apex:inputText value="{!PercentageOfClose}" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr><td colspan="3">
           <apex:outputLabel styleClass="errorMsg" value="{!Message}"/></td></tr>
</table>

    </apex:pageBlock>
```

**Apex code for saving:**

```
public PageReference SaveUpdateCRMInfo()
{

 MYCRM__c objCrm=new MYCRM__c();

 objCrm.FirstName__c=FirstName;
 objCrm.LastName__c=LastName;
 objCrm.LeadDate__c=LeadDate;
 objCrm.ExpectedCloseDate__c=ExpectedCloseDate;
 objCrm.CrmType__c='p';
 objCrm.IndustryTypeId__c=Integer.valueOf(selectedIndustry);
 objCrm.StatusId__c=Integer.valueOf(selectedStatus);
 objCrm.Value__c=Value;
 objCrm.PercentageOfClose__c=PercentageOfClose;
 objCrm.ChannelId__c=Integer.valueOf(selectedChannel);
 objCrm.OwnerId__c=Integer.valueOf(selectedOwner);

 insert objCrm;

return null;

}
```

Comment: We don't see the callout and it's hard to figure you process or sequence which is going on.

Comment: Callout is used to bind the dropdowns. These functions are using callouts - ChannelOptions, StatusOptions,IndustryOptions, Owneroptions

Answer (score 0):

A Web Service Callout may not occur after a DML statement within the same transaction. This is not allowed because it would potentially leave an uncommitted transaction open for many seconds which is expensive for the platform.

Possibly your transaction must be separated into two parts so that the DML transaction is completed before the Web Service Callout occurs.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for the quick reply. Could you please tell me how to do that? as i am not doing the callouts in "Save" function. Functions to bind the dropdowns are separate. These functions are using callouts - ChannelOptions, StatusOptions,IndustryOptions, Owneroptions. Are these automatically being called on button click too?

Comment: I would recommend that you search here for "You have uncommitted work pending" ==> http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=You%20have%20uncommitted%20work%20pending - you can skip those results about tests and fokus on the rest. One suggestion is, to move callouts in @future methods. You didn't provide all the code in your question and it's hard look into all details. So you should try this now on your own.

Comment: An approach in your case could be to retrieve the your values using AJAX or rerender a few seconds after pageload.